# Send output from make run to a file

Tags: bash, makefile

I'm trying to send an output of a `make run` to a file.

The problem is that when I try to do this: `make run > output`, it also sends the executed line from `make run`.

My `make run` is like this:

```
run:
        ./$(NAME)
```

The output should be something like this:

```
12341105 ACC
```

But it shows the run command also:

```
./sample
12341105 ACC
```

How can I get the output of the command generated from Makefile?

OBS: I don't want to do this inside the Makefile file.

Comment: `--silent` or `@./$(NAME). RTM: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html#Echoing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a silent switch in the make command as pointed out by James.

`make -s run > output`